# Duplicate Symbols Error - Google sign in and Google Analytics Both

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-analytics, google-plus

I am getting this error after including the google analytics in my app.
I have already implemented google plus sign in with framworks.
GoogleOpenSource and GooglePlus.

I have removed -ObjC from other linker flag.Still getting error.
After that I have added $(inherited) in other linked flag.

Is this error is coming because of google sign in is implemented already and I added google analytics via CocoaPods.

Please help. . . . .

```
  duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/TM cocoa analytics/TM4/trunk/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    /Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/TM cocoa analytics/TM4/trunk/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAICompressionUtil.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/TM cocoa analytics/TM4/trunk/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    /Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/TM cocoa analytics/TM4/trunk/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/TM cocoa analytics/TM4/trunk/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAITrackerImpl.o)
    /Users/pws-mac-2/Desktop/TM cocoa analytics/TM4/trunk/Pods/GoogleAnalytics/Libraries/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIAnalyticsPropertiesStore.o)
ld: 56 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Any luck with a solution or workaround?

Comment: I have the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying with Simulator. Try with iphone device.

Hope this will run.